# How to use PPMD with 7z under Linux?

Tags: linux, 7z

How can I use the 7z compression with PPMD algorithm? It produces better compression than the default in 7z.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-m` option to specify the compression method; for example:

```
7z a -mm=PPMd demo.zip demo.txt
```

creates a `demo.zip` archive containing `demo.txt` compressed using PPMd.

PPMd is only supported in ZIP and 7z archives; for the latter, the syntax is:

```
7z a -m0=PPMd demo.7z demo.txt
```

Note also that Info-Zip `unzip` (the version usually available on Linux systems) can't uncompress PPMd-compressed files in ZIP archives.

The [documentation](https://documentation.help/7-Zip-18.0/method.htm) has all the details.